# Handle &mdash; while import csv file using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had written code (in C#) about to import csv file using [filehelper](http://www.filehelpers.com/).
I am facing one issue that if file contain any [&mdash (—)](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html) than it would replace by ? character (not exact ? instead some special character as per shown in below image)

[image]

How can i handle this by code?

Thanks.

Comment: you can check by setting the Unicode to see if it is a special character. And if you are going to store in db, you can use the `nvarchar` data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your stream reader object is created ? Have you provided any specific encoding to it ? I think you should try if not yet, as default encoding can not be detected while there is no BOM defined.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx)

> The character encoding is set by the encoding parameter, and the
>   buffer size is set to 1024 bytes. The StreamReader object attempts to
>   detect the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream.
>   It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and
>   big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte
>   order marks. Otherwise, the user-provided encoding is used. See the
>   Encoding.GetPreamble method for more information.